# How to provide Jenkins pipeline script (Jenkinsfile) during runtime to each jobs running on a same jenkins instance?

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a jenkins instance running on a docker container, currently i'm utilizing 'Pipeline script from SCM' option for providing Jenkins pipeline scripts. Is there any way , that I could keep my jenkinsfile in the same container as my jenkins instance and use it everytime I trigger a job using that jenkins instance , instead of hosting it outside in some SCM and pulling it each time I trigger a job

Comment: Use the regular Pipeline project type; there's an option to define the Jenkinsfile contents in the project configuration.

Comment: Are you planning to change Jenkinsfile directly on the Jenkins server? 
Ideally Jenkinsfile should be in the source code/repo . Any specific reason for taking it out of repo?

Comment: I think that actually goes against the pipeline as code philosophy, which allows you to control  WHAT and HOW to deploy from inside the repo

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local git repository in the same container as your Jenkins instance, commit your scripts there and then in the field `Pipeline script from SCM -> Git -> Repository URL` put a file URI of your local repository (for example `file:///c/Users/Vitalii/repositories/jenkinsPipelines`).